# Autodesk Forge - Premium Reporting API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a question about Premium Reporting API. With usage-queries
(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/insights/v1/reference/http/usage-queries-POST/) I can't use fields like emailAddress, firstName, lastName ecc. ecc. even if, in autodesk account, I set tre privacy flag on as you can see in the image below reported. [image: image attached]

Here my postman [image]

TIA
Alder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been identified and a solution will be available by 14th Feb for specific fields.  [Check here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/insights/v1/change_history/changelog_v1/)